# Does react change the controlled input value even when the state hasn't changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

So if every UI update must happen only when "state" or "props" for a component change then why does the controlled input change back to the value that is inside the state, when the state wasn't updated and nothing has triggered an update cycle?

Comment: Show us the code you're referring to please.

Answer (score 0):

In a controlled component the value is equal to the one you pass in it as a prop.

If that value doesn't change then the value of that controlled component doesn't change either.

So usually in controlled components you would pass as the onChange prop a callback function which changes the value. If that callback function does not change the value then the value of the input is not changed.

E.g

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => {}} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

No matter how much we try to write into this input it's value will always remain an empty string "". Since the on change method is not updating the value state.

So to be clear on your question the state is not being reverted to the initial value instead it's never changing and same goes for the html element - the value of the input is never changing.

codepen sample: https://codepen.io/besnikkorca/pen/rNOVXzx